# laravel livewire delete record renders only after page refresh

Tags: laravel, page-refresh, laravel-livewire

This is my function to delete a search record from the database. I expect the DB changes to be rendered without a page refresh. and that's y I use livewire. but after clicking delete, the page is updated only after refresh. the dd results don't show updated results.

```
public function deleteSearch($search) {
    $empsearch = Auth::user()->mySearches->find($search);
    $empsearch->delete();
    $this->skills = Auth()->user()->mySearches;
    dd($this->skills);
}
```

**Blade file**

```
@if (count($skills) > 0)
    @foreach ($skills as $search)
        <div class="el-tag" >
            <a href="/search?query={{ $search->name }}">
                {{ $search->name }}
            </a>
            |
            <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" wire:click.prevent="deleteSearch({{ $search->search_id }})" >
                <i class="pl-1 icon el-icon-delete"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

These are the **mount and render methods**

```
public $preference;
public $skills;

public function mount($preference) {
    $this->preference = $preference;
    $this->skills = Auth()->user()->mySearches;
}

public function render() {
    return view('livewire.preferences');
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the blade file for your component.

Comment: @Peppermintology please check my blade file. thanks

Comment: what version of livewire are you using 1x or 2x

Answer (score 0):

In the render method, the return statement is returning complete HTML DOM (i.e. return view('livewire.preferences') ) due to which the changes are taking place/reflecting only after the page refresh/reload.

Solution:-

1. Make the delete request with the help of ajax
2. Then on success of ajax request, update the main intendent DOM (i.e. the body part) so that the changes will be reflected without page refresh.

Comment: vishal, im at the beginning stage learning laravel and i really dont know those terms request with help of ajax. and because livewire updates live, i thought it could simply reflect changes.

Answer (score 0):

after delete statement try this for get fresh data from records

```
$this->skills = Auth()->user()->mySearches->refresh();
```

UPDATED
Ok maybe must be only like this:

```
$this->skills->refresh();
```

Comment: i got this error. Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::refresh does not exist.